# SQL: How to Create Table with a time condition?

Tags: sql, time, constraints

I am currently learning SQL for University and my teacher asked me to create a table for the following scheme:

Class: Room, StartTime (automatically add 90mins), Day, ClassName, optionalComment

With the following conditions:

- one class can have multiple occurrences
- a Room can only be taken up by one class at a time
- a Room can be occupied by different classes at different times

I am just stuck with this one. I was thinking about constraints, but not really figuring anything out.

Can someone maybe push my mind in the right direction?

Thank you!

EDIT: This is what I got so far, as I said - I am very stuck.

```
create table class (
    room varchar(10) not null
    day varchar(100) not null
    className varchar(255) not null
    optionalComment varchar(255)
    startTime time )
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: what's your understanding and what you've tried so far any facing issues? that's what I'm asking

Comment: I cannot figure out how to even give the starTime the 'adds 90 mins automatically'. And not how to condition this, to send an error, if I try to Insert a class which overlaps with another class.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I don't understand the "*automatically add 90mins*" part. Do you mean when you insert `08:00` that value should turn into `09:30` when stored in the database?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. It’s more like a timeframe. I add the value „random class in room A“ startTime: 8:00. Then if I try to add another class in room A at 9:00 it should say that room a is blocked till 9:30

Comment: Since I am just at the beginning of the lecture it should not be this complicated. I’ve learned about data types, primary and foreign keys. But I can’t figure it out tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html), CHECK constraints can not check data in other rows; what you want to look into is a TRIGGER. This seems a bit advanced for a first lesson, but they're pretty straightforward:

- Whenever you attempt to INSERT into the table, your TRIGGER is *triggered* and will perform your safety check BEFORE INSERT to see if any other row exists where ROOM is the same and New_Class_Start_Time is BETWEEN startTime and startTime+90 minutes.
- If it finds such a row, the trigger should deny the INSERT and maybe throw a nice, friendly error message to the user.
- If it does not find the row, perform the actual INSERT statement.

You can review [basic TRIGGER behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/trigger-definition.html) and syntax, but [this looks like it might be exactly what you need](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/). Here's a skeleton example of the logic you could implement in a trigger. Please note I don't guarantee this identical syntax works in Postgres; I'm a native SQL Server and Oracle user, but the logic will be similar to:

```sql
IF EXISTS (
           select 1
           from class c 
           where c.day = NEW.day 
              AND c.room = NEW.room 
              AND ( /* we have to check for whether the class would start during the existing class 
                       OR end during an existing class */
                   NEW.startTime BETWEEN c.startTime and c.startTime + interval '90 minutes'
                   OR NEW.startTime + interval '90 minutes' BETWEEN c.startTime and c.startTime + interval '90 minutes')
) THEN 
     -- FAIL GRACEFULLY 
ELSE
     -- ALLOW INSERT 
END IF;
```